# .NET Core API saving image upload asynchronously with ImageSharp, MemoryStream and FileStream

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, filestream, memorystream, imagesharp

I have a .NET Core API that I'd like to extend to save uploaded images asynchronously.

Using ImageSharp I should be able to check uploads and resize if predefined size limits are exceeded. However I can't get a simple async save working.

A simple (non-async) save to file works without problem:

My Controller extracts IFormFile from the upload and calls the following method without any problem

```
public static void Save(IFormFile image, string imagesFolder)
{
    var fileName = Path.Combine(imagesFolder, image.FileName);

    using (var stream = image.OpenReadStream())
    using (var imgIS = Image.Load(stream, out IImageFormat format))
    {
        imgIS.Save(fileName);
    }
}
```

ImageSharp is currently lacking [async methods](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/272) so a workaround is necessary.

The updated code below saves the uploaded file but the format is incorrect - when viewing the file I get the message "**It appears we don't support this file format**".

The format is extracted from the ImageSharp Load method. and used when saving to MemoryStream.

MemoryStream CopyToAsync method is used to save to FileStream to make the upload asynchronous.

```
public static async void Save(IFormFile image, string imagesFolder)
{
    var fileName = Path.Combine(imagesFolder, image.FileName);

    using (var stream = image.OpenReadStream())
    using (var imgIS = Image.Load(stream, out IImageFormat format))
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {      
        imgIS.Save(memoryStream, format);

        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        fileStream.Flush();
        memoryStream.Close();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

I can't work out whether the issue is with ImageSharp Save to MemoryStream, or the MemoryStream.CopyToAsync.

I'm currently getting 404 on [SixLabors docs](https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/ImageSharp/GettingStarted.html) - hopefully not an indication that the project has folded.

How can I make the upload async and save to file in the correct format?

Comment: doc urls have changed as part of the RC1 release... you can access the docs by going directly to https://docs.sixlabors.com/ rather than directly to an article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CopyToAsync` copies a stream starting at its current position. You must change the current position of `memoryStream` back to start before copying:

```cs
    // ...
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
   // ...
```